# Difference between dropStyle and raiseStyle in ExtJS

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I'm trying to generate a candlestick chart in ExtJS (Sencha) and I noticed 2 `style` properties:

```
style: {
        dropStyle: {
            fill: 'rgb(237,123,43)',
            stroke: 'rgb(237,123,43)'
        },
        raiseStyle: {
            fill: 'rgb(55,153,19)',
            stroke: 'rgb(55,153,19)'
        }}
```

This [sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1qo3&view/editor) has the `dropStyle` as orange and the `raiseStyle` as green. I don't understand why some are green and some are orange. What's the threshold value for the candlestick to change from orange to green and vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

`dropStyle` - **dropstyle is used   to style the candel if security lower than it opened.**

`raiseStyle` - **raiseStyle is used to style the candle if security closed higher than its opened**.

For more reference you check out this link. [Reference Book](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/src/CandleStick.js-1.html)

Also This link will help you the candelStick programm flow where you can see how exactly `dropStyle` and `raiseStyle` works.

[CandelStick](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/src/CandleStick.js-1.html)